# How to complete SKAction before looping again

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I have a function that moves rectangles around a SKScene using a for loop. Is there a way to make it so that that the rectangles move as soon as the SKAction is called? It waits to run the SKAction until the loop is finished, which isn't what I'm trying to do.

Here is an example of my code:

```
for i in 0...newHeights.count-1 {
     for j in stride(from: 0, to: newHeights.count-i-1, by: 1){
          let moveRect = SKAction.moveTo(x: rectangles[j].position.x, duration: 5)
          moveRect.timingMode = SKActionTimingMode.easeInEaseOut
          rectangles[j+1].run(moveRect)
          let sequence = SKAction.sequence([moveRect])
          rectangles[j+1].run(sequence)
      }
}
```

edit: now that part is working, but it moves in unexpected ways. I can just switch the positions by doing

```
rectangles[j].position.x = rectangles[j+1].position.x
rectangles[j+1].position.x = y
```

but when I try to use SKActions to move them it moves them in a completely different way.

```
let moveRect = SKAction.moveTo(x: rectangles[j+1].position.x, duration: 1)
            //moveRect.timingMode = SKActionTimingMode.easeInEaseOut
            let waitAction = SKAction.wait(forDuration: 2)
            let sequence = SKAction.sequence([moveRect, waitAction])

            let moveRect2 = SKAction.moveTo(x: y, duration: 1)
            moveRect2.timingMode = SKActionTimingMode.easeInEaseOut
            let waitAction2 = SKAction.wait(forDuration: 2)
            let sequence2 = SKAction.sequence([moveRect2, waitAction2])

            rectangles[j].run(sequence) {
                self.rectangles[j+1].run(sequence2)
            }
```

Comment: Try doing a waitFor duration action?

Comment: You didn't look up how SKActions work then.  They happen during the action phase of the update cycle and will never fire immediately.  Your code here doesn't even make sense, why are you calling the moveRect action twice?

Comment: @Knight0fDragon I didn't mean to keep the sequence thing in there. That was me just trying to figure it out. I tried doing it without SKActions by just doing rectangles[j+1].position.x = rectangles[j].position.x, but that also didn't happen until the loop completed.

Comment: @Knight0fDragon Is there an alternative I can use that makes more sense for this? I'm just trying to visualize bubble sort by having the rectangles change places.

Comment: then you want to chain the actions together, on the completion of the last action, start the next action.

Comment: in your case,  I would just set all of the nodes speed settings to 0,  then add a runblock action that sets the next blocks speed to 1

Comment: @Knight0fDragon Thanks so much for the help. I think I figured out how to use sequences to chain together the events, but the movement isn't working properly. I edited my original post to show my problem. Maybe I'm not linking them together properly? I can't figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

As discussed in the comments, set speed to 0, then turn on the next nodes speed when the current node finishes

only problem, what happens to 0?  Is that intentionally blank?

```
for i in 0..<newHeights.count {
     for j in stride(from: 0, to: newHeights.count-i-1, by: 1){
          let moveRect = SKAction.moveTo(x: rectangles[j].position.x, duration: 5)
          let startNextRect = SKAction.run{if (j+2 < newHeights.count){self.rectangles[j+2].speed = 1}}
          moveRect.timingMode = SKActionTimingMode.easeInEaseOut
          let seq = SKAction.sequence([moveRect,startNextRect])
          rectangles[j+1].run(seq)
          rectangles[j+1].speed = 0

      }
}
rectangles[1].speed = 1
```